# Bull Dashboard status 404

Tags: javascript, queue

I'm trying to use the Bull Dashboard but it doesn't work.

It keeps "Loading..."

http://localhost:3003/undefined/queues/?

[Bull Dashboard Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OIDU.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I stoped using Helmet and now it's working.

Issue: https://github.com/vcapretz/bull-board/issues/130